How can I fix datetime error when trying to use the now syntax?
I am trying to run the code below but when I do, I keep getting errors, i managed to change the import syntax from

import datatime as dt

to

from datetime import date time as dt

This has worked but I am not getting the exact time I need. This is what I got instead

Timestamp('2024-07-04 00:00:00')

How can I fix this?

What are you trying to get? What are you running to get that Timestamp?

If I understand you correctly, use from datetime import datetime as dt and call dt.now() to get the correct date and time.

This was the syntax I used that I got the current timestamp in the original question reference_date = pd.Timestamp(dt.now().date())

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example in its entirety.  @David

Saying .now().date() specifically asks that the time be stripped off.  If you don't want that, well, don't DO that.

If you just want to get today's date without hours / minutes /  seconds, you can use:
from datetime import date

date.today()
>>> datetime.date(2024, 7, 4)

Alternatively for right now:
from datetime import datetime

datetime.now()
>>> datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 4, 12, 46, 30, 841567)

